# R - POST command. Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining

Tags: r, curl, post, httr

I am having an issue with the following httr POST command

```
try(POST("https://marketsgateway.pjm.com/marketsgateway/xml/query", add_headers(.headers = headers),body=uptoXML,verbose()),silent=FALSE)
```

It returns this message:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
```

It seems I need to somehow change the POST settings to get all of the data. When the request is for a smaller set of data, it works fine. But when it's just a bit larger, I get this memory error. I have searched for R solutions, but cannot find how to tinker with the POST defaults to get it to pull all of the data chunks.

Below is the verbose output (with sensitive cookie data changed):

```
-> POST /marketsgateway/xml/query HTTP/1.1
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.35.0 r-curl/3.2 httr/1.4.2
-> Host: marketsgateway.pjm.com
-> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
-> Cookie: xxxxxxxxx
-> Content-Type: text/xml
-> Content-Length: 289
-> 
>> <?xml version="1.0"?>
>>     <Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
>>       <Header/>
>>       <Body>
>>         <QueryRequest xmlns="http://emkt.pjm.com/emkt/xml">
>>           <QueryUpToTransactionResults day="2020-08-09"/> 
>>         </QueryRequest> 
>>       </Body>
>>     </Envelope>

<- HTTP/1.1 302 Found
<- Connection: keep-alive
<- Location: https://sso.pjm.com/access/UI/Login?goto=https%3A%2F%2Fmarketsgateway.pjm.com%3A443%2Fmarketsgateway%2Fxml%2Fquery
<- Content-Length: 0
<- Date: Tue, 11 Aug 2020 00:10:57 GMT
<- Set-Cookie: MARKETSGATEWAY=xxxxxxxxx;Path=/;Version=1;Secure;Httponly
<- 
-> GET /access/UI/Login?goto=https%3A%2F%2Fmarketsgateway.pjm.com%3A443%2Fmarketsgateway%2Fxml%2Fquery HTTP/1.1
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.35.0 r-curl/3.2 httr/1.4.2
-> Host: sso.pjm.com
-> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
-> Cookie: xxxxxxxxxxx
-> Content-Type: text/xml
-> Content-Length: 289
-> 
<- HTTP/1.1 302 
<- Date: Tue, 11 Aug 2020 00:10:57 GMT
<- Location: /access/XUI/?goto=https://marketsgateway.pjm.com:443/marketsgateway/xml/query#login/
<- X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://esuite.pjm.com
<- Content-Length: 0
<- Set-Cookie: SSO=xxxxxxxxxxxx; path=/; Httponly; Secure
<- Connection: close
<- Set-Cookie: AMDistAuthCookie=https://sso.pjm.com:443/das/UI/Login
<- 
-> GET /access/XUI/?goto=https://marketsgateway.pjm.com:443/marketsgateway/xml/query HTTP/1.1
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.35.0 r-curl/3.2 httr/1.4.2
-> Host: sso.pjm.com
-> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-> Cookie: SSO=xxxxxxxxxx
-> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
-> Cookie: xxxxxxxxxxx
-> Content-Type: text/xml
-> Content-Length: 289
-> 
<- HTTP/1.1 200 
<- Accept-Ranges: bytes
<- Cache-Control: public, max-age=300
<- Date: Tue, 11 Aug 2020 00:10:57 GMT
<- ETag: W/"1410-1577378972000"
<- Last-Modified: Thu, 26 Dec 2019 16:49:32 GMT
<- X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://esuite.pjm.com
<- Content-Type: text/html
<- Connection: close
<- Location: 
<- Set-Cookie: AMDistAuthCookie=https://sso.pjm.com:443/das/UI/Login
<- Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<-
```